# Using the digits $0,3,5,6,8$ (without repetition) how many numbers can be created which will be greater than $4000$?

Tags: combinatorics

I have tried to solve this in following way:
Using $5$ digits we can create $5!$ numbers. As there is $0$,so if $0$ stays in all left(like $03658,05683,\dots$)then it will be $4$ digit number. As the numbers must be greater than $4000$,so after the placement of zero, we can't place $3$. So if these type of numbers can be created in $3!$ ways, then the answer must be $(5!-3!)$ or $114$.
But my book says $168$.
How is this possible?

Comment: You have not counted 4-digit numbers that contain a zero

Comment: thanks man that was a silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 5-digit numbers, the first digit can be anything but 0 (4 choices), the 2nd digit can be any remaining digit (4 choices), the 3rd any remaining digit (3 choices) and so on. Total $4\times4\times3\times2\times1=96$.

For 4-digit numbers, the first digit can be anything but 0 or 3 (3 choices), the 2nd digit can be any remaining digit (4 choices), the 3rd any remaining digit (3 choices) and so on. Total $3\times4\times3\times2=72$.

Grand total 168.

Comment: yes you are right